# combination of pair subsets from a list in lisp

Tags: list, lisp, subset

How to create all possible pairs subsets from a list in conman lisp. For example the list A contain four elements

```
list A= ("A" "B" "C" "D")  

the expected output is as follows:

(("A","B"),("A","C"), ("A","D"),("B","C"),("B","D"), ("C","D"))
```

Could someone please help me out to generate these subsets.
Thanks a lot

Comment: What have you tried and what problem is preventing you from solving this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read up on [`mapcar` et al](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_mapc_.htm):

```
(defparameter a (list 1 2 3 4))
(mapcon (lambda (tail)
          (mapcar (lambda (x)
                    (cons (car tail) x))
                  (cdr tail)))
        a)
==> ((1 . 2) (1 . 3) (1 . 4) (2 . 3) (2 . 4) (3 . 4))
```

Comment: Just need to clarify regarding the sublists, for example (1 . 2)  from above output, I am unable to read the element from the sublist. I have tried as follows:

Comment: Just need to clarify regarding the sublists, for example (1 . 2)  from the above output, I am unable to read the element from the sublists. I have tried as follows: I have setq the above results in outputlist and iterate through (dolist (x outputlist) (print x) (nth 0 x)) but got error.Is it possible we can get sublist result without dot so that we could read the elements of the sublists. Print x  is printed the sublist element but we can not read element of the sublists. Actually I want to iterate the values of sublists. your help would highly be appreciated.

Comment: to get lists `(1 2)` instead of cons cells `(1 . 2)`, use `list` instead of `cons`. However you should stick with `cons` and use `car` and `cdr` instead of `nth`.