# How to create list of lists from one single list with odd and even pair in common lisp

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I am new in Lisp programming and trying to create sublists from one single list in lisp with pair of odd and even from the list. for example:
I have a list

```
ListA ("a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "f" "g" "h")
```

now I want to convert into the following list:

```
enter code here
ListB  ( ("a" "b") ("c" "d") ("e" "f") ("g" "h") )
```

so always sublist  will be generated with the value of ( (first second) (third fourth) (fifth sixth) ............)

I have tried with mutiple ways for example first take out odd item and even item  separate and used the function  (list (oddlist evenlist)) but not getting above expected values in the above ListB.Could someone please help me in this regard. Your help would  be highly appreciated.

Comment: What should the result be for a list with an odd number of elements?

Comment: I don't generally point out typos, but please note that the language is "Common Lisp", not "Comman Lisp", or (as in [your earlier question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28942009/1281433)) "Conman Lisp".  (Though there have probably been a few con-man Lispers out there.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually *very* short with **loop**:

```
(loop for (x y) on '(a b c d e f) by #'cddr
      collect (list x y))
;=> ((A B) (C D) (E F))
```

This does give you a NIL in the last pair if you have an odd number of elements, but you didn't mention what should happen in that case:

```
(loop for (x y) on '(a b c d e f g ) by #'cddr
      collect (list x y))
;=> ((A B) (C D) (E F) (G NIL))
```

Comment: Many Thanks Joshua! Worked Perfectly. Very much sorry for typo

Answer (score 1):

You need to make a procedure that does the following:

1. handle when argument is (). Usually the result is ()
2. default case you handle one chain of two. eg. `(cons (list "a" "b") recursive-call-here)`

So the result of `'("g" "h")` becomes `(cons (list "g" "h") ())` and if you add that to recursive-call-here backwards you end up with:

```
(cons (list "a" "b") 
      (cons (list "c" "d") 
            (cons (list "e" "f") 
                  (cons (list "g" "h") ())))) 
; ==> (("a" "b") ("c" "d") ("e" "f") ("g" "h"))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you already have the even elements separated from the odd ones as you seemed to suggest, the next step would be:

```
(mapcar #'list evenlist oddlist)
```

Which one comes first, `evenlist` or `oddlist`, depends on whether you started counting from 0 or 1.

Or, the whole problem can be tackled with a single `loop` expression:

```
(loop for head = '(a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p) then (cddr head)
   until (null head)
     if (= (length head) 1) collect head
     else collect (subseq head 0 2))
```

Comment: This is a much more complicated use of LOOP than what's needed here.  You can just `(loop for (x y) on '(a b c d e f) by #'cddr collect (list x y))`, as I've shown in [another answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29322735/1281433).

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor Thanks, I didn't know `loop` could do that. I've corrected my Racket implementation of the `loop` macro on PLaneT so it works there, too.