# Sublist in common lisp

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I have list of lists in my program 
for example

```
 (( a b) (c d) (x y) (d u) ........)
```

Actually I want to add 1 new element in the list but new element would be a parent of all existing sublists.

for example if a new element is z, so my list should become like this

```
  ( (z( a b) (c d) (x y) (d u) ........))
```

I have tried with push new element but it list comes like this

```
  ( z( a b) (c d) (x y) (d u) ........)
```

that I dont want as I have lot of new elements coming in and each element represents some block of sublists in the list

Your help would highly be appreciated.

Comment: As [I've mentioned before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29314957/how-to-create-list-of-lists-from-one-single-list-with-odd-and-even-pair-in-commo#comment46836370_29314957), it's "Common Lisp".

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you just need to wrap the result of **push**, **cons**, or **list*** in another list:

```
(defun add-parent (children parent)
  (list (list* parent children)))

(add-parent '((a b) (c d) (x y) (d u)) 'z)
;;=> ((Z (A B) (C D) (X Y) (D U)))
```

This is the approach that I'd probably take with this.  It's just important that you save the return value.  In this regard, it's sort of like the **sort** function.

However, if you want to make a destructive macro out of that, you can do that too using **define-modify-macro**.  In the following, we use [**define-modify-macro**](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_defi_2.htm) to define a macro **add-parentf** that updates its first argument to be the result of calling **add-parent** (defined above) with the first argument and the parent.

```
(define-modify-macro add-parentf (parent) add-parent)

(let ((kids (copy-tree '((a b) (c d) (x y) (d u)))))
  (add-parentf kids 'z)
  kids)
;;=> ((Z (A B) (C D) (X Y) (D U)))
```

Answer (score 0):

For such a simple case you can also use a shorter backquote approach, for example:

```
(let ((parent 'z) (children '((a b) (c d) (e f))))
    `((,parent ,@children)))
```

If you aren't familiar with backquote, I'd recommend reading the nice and concise description in Appendix D: Read Macros of Paul Graham's ANSI Common Lisp.